# Зачем "бесхозяйный", если есть "бесхозный"?

Tags: словообразование

Встретилось мне слово "бесхозяйный", и сразу возник вопрос: "В чем разница по сравнению с широко употребляемым "бесхозный"? Предполагаю (об этом записано в словаре), что "бесхозяйный" - это юридический термин. Но никак не могу понять, в чем разница?

Answer (score 6):

*Бесхозный* is a variant of *бесхозяйный*. It had appeared in the late 1910s and took on since, having almost completely replaced the original by the 1950s.

Before the 1910s, *бесхозяйный* was the only acceptable variant:

> - Поселение казаков на бесхозяйном Яике могло казаться завоеванием, коего важность была очевидна. *// [А. С. Пушкин. История Пугачева (1833)]*
> - Где-то под вагонами чавкает предприимчивый поросёнок, и бесхозяйная собака трусливо шарахнулась в сторону. *// [С. С. Кондурушкин. Вслед за войной (1915)]*
> - Ступай и бери: виноградники, и сады, и дачи, все ― бесхозяйное, все ― пустое! *// [И. С. Шмелев. Солнце мертвых (1923)]*

Legalese is conservative (not only in Russian).

In Russian legalese we have words like *деяние, одаряемый, мена* etc. which sound funny to the modern ear, yet are still widely used in law.

Comment: Спасибо большое за интересное объяснение. А я-то думал, что "бесхозяйный" возникло позже как вариант от "бесхозный" и именно как юридический термин